# When ARC working? Compilation or runtime?

Tags: objective-c, swift, automatic-ref-counting

In Objective-C or Swift when ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) is working? On compilation or on run time stage? And why is it matter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Apple's [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> **ARC** is a compiler feature that provides automatic memory management of Objective-C objects.
>
> Instead of you having to remember when to use retain, release, and autorelease, **ARC** evaluates the lifetime requirements of your objects and automatically inserts appropriate memory management calls for you at compile time. The compiler also generates appropriate dealloc methods for you.

**Example ARC enabled class:**

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;
@end

@implementation Person

// ARC insert dealloc method & associated memory 
// management calls at compile time.
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [_firstName release];
    [_lastName release];
}

@end
```

Comment: The real answer is both at compile time and at runtime.  There is code emitted such that a frame can know if another frame of execution is ARC or not and avoid the autoreleasepool, when possible.

Answer (score 14):

The compiler inserts the necessary `retain`/`release` calls at compile time, but those calls are executed at runtime, just like any other code.